# Are the doors of resurrection in Genshin Impact simply checkpoints?

Tags: genshin-impact

While playing Genshin Impact last night, I encountered several doors of resurrection while working on one of my objectives:

[image: Screenshot of an activated door of resurrection.]

My initial guess was that this serves as a checkpoint of sorts, and searches online seem to line up with that, [with one](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/270518-genshin-impact/79024056) specifically stating:

> You respawn there when you inevitably mess up an air current jump.

However, I never actually saw them in action outside of being activated when passing by. As a result, I can't help but feel a little disappointed in the idea of them simply being checkpoints.

---

Do the doors of resurrection serve any other purpose in the game outside of being simply checkpoints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do the doors of resurrection serve any other purpose in the game outside of being simply checkpoints?

As of right now, no. They are checkpoints for when you die in the dungeon, allowing you to re-spawn then rather than having to restart the dungeon. Keep in mind that usually you only have 10 uses of checkpoints per domain attempt, falling through the map limit doesn't count for this limit though.